# LibreELEC - exit to command line?

Tags: pi-2, kodi

I downloaded and installed LibreELEC 7.0.3 onto RPI2 and it won't connect to WIFI. I can't even view logs via KODI standard UI.

The power button on the left bottom does not have 'exit' option - only reboot and shutdown and custom shutdown timer. Is there a way to exit to command line or boot to it?

Comment: LibreELEC has a [connections page](https://wiki.libreelec.tv/index.php?title=LibreELEC_Settings#tab=Connections) in its settings which deals with everything network related. Everything filled out OK in there? [Ethernet turned on](https://wiki.libreelec.tv/index.php?title=LibreELEC_Settings#tab=Network) if appropriate? The instructions on connecting using SSH are [here](https://wiki.libreelec.tv/index.php?title=Accessing_LibreELEC) if you want to get in that way.

Comment: I can't connect because I can't get it to connect to wifi. Everything on the connections page is fine, it just won't connect. I can't understand their rationale to remove the 'exit' power option from kodi.